# Unicode App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I have a problem from this morning. My app was working well without any issue. From this morning I'm facing below problem:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /base/data/home/apps/s~gestionalemeraviglie/35.386401329554667154/scriptemail.py on line 35, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I haven't modified the code, so I can't understand what is going on.
Is any change on App Engine Python Unicode management?

Right now I'm using :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add on the top of your file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`.

Comment: Done! Thanks. I had a couple of files without the coding. But I still can't understand why it was working in the last couple of year, and yesterday stopped working.